# Display data for tommorow evertime current date is selected

Tags: php, date, datepicker

[image]

I have a project where, when a specific date is selected, the data should show the following date, not the same date as selected on the calendar.

Sample calendar date is May 17, the date should show May 18, every time I upload form excel to SQL the date will just display the date selected on the calendar

Comment: Could you show us the content of the variable containing the current date?

Comment: Increment the date and query like this select  * from table where date(created_at) >= date_add(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);

Comment: @KiranRaiChamling: Your comment seems to be intended as an answer. In that case write an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete info, I use ajax to accomplish this. I was able to fix the initial load, using $tomorrow1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('tomorrow')); and $tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today')); now my problem in on my ajax page here what happen on the initial load https://ibb.co/WgSth7M

Comment: @KiranRaiChamling how can I declare it here:  $sql_hid=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `appointmentlog` WHERE `status`='Y' AND `appointment_date`='' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Appointment_time, '%9:%i %p') ASC");

Answer (score 0):

You can query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM appointmentlog WHERE status='Y' AND date(appointment_date)=date_add(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Appointment_time, '%9:%i %p')");
```

I hope you are sending the date as one of your ajax post parameters.

In date_add() function replace now() by the date passed to your backend.